# Select all option values not first

Tags: jquery

I have a script that is working that show/hides divs based on the drop down option selected.

I need to hide all divs except the 1rst div prior to user making a selection in the drop down.

Based on the script below, how can I get the values from all the options except the first option so I can hide all divs except the first div?

```
$('.dd-show-hide').find('option:not(:first)').val().hide();

$('.dd-show-hide').change(function(){
   $(this).find('option').each(function(){
      $('#' + this.value).hide();
    });
    $('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

```
<select class="dd-show-hide">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="div1">Show Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Show Div 2</option>
</select>

<div  id="div1" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 1</div>
<div  id="div2" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 2</div>
```

Comment: I prefer to select the div to show based on the 1rst drop-down option. That way the script is portable and can be used on any dropdown. Instead of having to select a div  ID each time to manually hide/show.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can use `first` selector and `not` method:

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').not(':first').hide();
```

Or trigger the change event, there is no need to use the `each` method.

```
var $divs = $('.drop-down-show-hide');
$('.dd-show-hide').change(function(){
   $divs.hide().filter('[id='+this.value+']').show();
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when I have to "hide all things except *_*" in JQuery, I find it more convenient to hide them all, then show the one I want. This hides all but the first:

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide().first().show();
```

This hides based on the currently selected option:

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide().filter('#' + $('.dd-show-hide').val()).show();
```

This hides based on the first option (even if not necessarily the one selected now)

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide().filter('#'+$('.dd-show-hide option:first').val()).show()
```

You don't need to go through the ids one by one. To show only the one selected in the dropdown and hide the others:

```
$('.dd-show-hide').change(function() {
   $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide().filter('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

Comment: This does assume that the one OP wants to hide is the first one as opposed to the one with id 'div1'

Comment: @LeeMeador That's the question.

Comment: The option values contain the div ID so I prefer to make the script portable by using the option values to show/hide the divs rather than having to each time manually name the divs in question.

Comment: Why not using `this.value` instead of `$(this).find('option:selected').val()`?

Comment: You are right. Sort of. The question says "first option" and "first div" both. It isn't certain that OP means 'first' in the sense of 'farther towards the top of the HTML' or 'first' in the sense of 'with div1 as id'

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You almost had it:

```
$('.dd-show-hide').find('option').each(function(){
      if ('div1' != this.value) {
          $('#' + this.value).hide();
      } else {
          $('#' + this.value).show();
      }
 });
```