# Hide div based on option value

Tags: jquery

How can I change this to hide all divs that match option values EXCEPT the first div?

What I have so far does the job of hiding all divs before a selection is made however I need to have the first div showing before the user makes a choice.

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/fj63g/

```
$('.dd-show-hide').find('option').each(function(){
    $('#' + this.value).hide();
});


$('.dd-show-hide').change(function(){
   $(this).find('option').each(function(){
      $('#' + this.value).hide();
    });
    $('#' + this.value).show();
});

<select class="dd-show-hide">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="div1">Show Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Show Div 2</option>
    <option value="div3">Show Div 3</option>
</select>

<div  id="div1" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 1</div>
<div  id="div2" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 2</div>
<div  id="div3" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 3</div>
```

Comment: Scarily similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760705/select-all-option-values-not-first/14760795). What happened?

Answer (score 1):

replacing `$('.dd-show-hide').find('option')` with `$('.dd-show-hide').find('option:gt(1)')` should be ok

Comment: Yup. That works. Never used Greater Than before. I like it.